# How to start working on a screen whether other data is loading?

Tags: jquery, sql, model-view-controller, ado.net

I have a project in mvc. In the registration page of Students, there are 3 screens. First screen contains the total students of the institute. total number of records are 20,000 approx. second screen shows current day's registered students details. Third screen has registration form. 
When page loads, it takes time to load because of 20,000 records of first screen. I want that registration window should load first and start working. It should not wait for other screen records. If other screens are taking time to load, it should be in process at backend but registration window should start working. 
What should I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on the assumption that you are using .NET. Is that correct ? Then you will want to look at asynchronous programming techniques. This a huge subject matter. There are lots of resources out there. Here's is one for starters. It would be difficult to attempt an answer to this question. I would suggest you read up on it, try a few things to see how you get on.

[Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also

[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Students/GetRecords", success: function (result) {
                    $("#studentList").html(result); 
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Look at this sample. You can use ajax and MVC together. Via Ajax you can load 
studentList div content. By the way this is a basic sample. You have to devolop according to your requirements. Also, If you have huge data Like 20.000 records that is so huge a webpage :) My recomantion for this that use Jquery DataTable

https://datatables.net/

May this plugin can solve your whole problem as totally